# Laravel eloquent model how to get data from relationship's table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, repository-pattern

I am developing a laravel application which has the following eloquent models

- **Product hasMany('App/Sku','products_id')**
- **Sku belongTO('App/Product')**

I have a controller 'ProductController' where the following code is available

```
public function index()
{    
    $products = Product::all();
    foreach($products as $product){
            $products_id = $product->products_id;
    }
}
```

I am exposing RESTfull API which will allow my users to get all product details (including skus, shipping types etc..).

Suppose if I have an API **GET : /products**

The code which fetches all the product details will be some what the following

```
public function index()
{              
      $products = Product::all();
      foreach($products as $product){
          $products_id = $product->products_id;
          $skus_data = Product::find($products_id)->skus;
      }
        // Now I have both the product details + skus which I can bundle into an array/json.
}
```

Now my question is , is this logic proper? In this case all the logics are in the controller since im using eloquent models I have a model for each table and the relationships are defined in it. Is there a way I can get all the details of a product/associated model (Products details (in table 1)+ Sku details (in table 2)) rather than using the below

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $products_id = $product->products_id;
    $skus_data = Product::find($products_id)->skus;
}
```

I am pretty new to laravel development and eloquent models. I will be using repository pattern for the development and in that case where does the aboe logic (Product+Sku combining) resides.

Please help out.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you can get the details of the products and skus without making one additional query per product using [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) 
 ( this is referred as the typical *N+1 query problem* where N is the number of the products )

Suppose the relation between your `Product` and `Sku` models model is:

**Product**

```
public function skus()
{
    return hasMany('App/Sku','products_id');
}
```

To fetch the products data along with the sku data you can use the `with` method. In your controller:

**Controller**

```
 $products = Product::with('skus')->get();
```

Then, in your views, you can get the info this way:

**View**

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
     //$product->skus is a collection of Sku models
     dd( $product->skus );
}
```

For the repository question: if you want to use a repository you can place the eloquent-access part of your code inside the repository. So, for example you could have this method inside the repository:

**ProductRepository**

```
public function getProductsData() 
{
    //access eloquent from the repository
    return Product::with('skus')->get();    
}
```

then you can use your repository in your controller:

**Controller**

```
//inject the repository in the controller
public function __construct( ProductRepository $productRepo )
{
    $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
}

//use the injected repository to get the data
public function index()
{
    $products = this->productRepo->getProductsData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One more query I am having from your answer is where does all my data validations happen? Is it in the controller or repository and can I treat a repository as a library like in codeigniter?

Comment: @user34305 : To validate the data you can do it in different way: in your controller, in your models, or using specific classes, it depends on your needs and preferences: check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) to get more info. For the codeigniter part i can't help as i don't use it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the repository pattern is used, do it like this.

```php
public function index() {
    $data = $this->passportRepository->with('user')->findWhere(['id'=>1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use eager loading.

```
 public function index()
 {
    $products = Product::with('skus')->get();
 }
```

This will give you an array of products that have a skus array in each product object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    foreach($products->skus as $product)
    {
         return $product;
    }

}
```

This will give you the exact result in the object form.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!